# Android Sqlite Journal

Tags: android, sqlite

I cant get rid of Journal file. Always roll back my DB. I tried db.close() on destroy even. How can I COMMIT my database?

How I use db simply ;

```
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: I even tried Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF", null); after this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase(); still no improvement